# .NET/C#: InvalidOperationException while trying to save new enum value

Tags: c#, .net, xml, serialization, enums

I have an existing .NET/C#-enum

```
public enum Model 
{
   Default = 0,
   Value1 = 1
}
```

that is property of a class.

The class is serialized and stored in a XML-File, e.g. like this:

```
<Model>Value1</Model>
```

Now I want expand the enum for a new item to

```
public enum Model 
{
   Default = 0,
    Value1 = 1,
    Value2 = 2
}
```

The build of sourcecode succeeds and the application starts, but when I try store the new value 'value2'

```
<Model>Value2</Model>
```

in the xml file, I get an `InvalidOperationException` with message:

> "Instance validation error: '2' is not a valid value for Model."

The problem [here](http://david-homer.blogspot.com/2013/10/c-enum-xml-serialization-instance.html) seems a similar one, but enum values ​​are removed or renamed.

Comment: If you search for `Value1` in your git repo, is it defined elsewhere as well?

Comment: Tip : don't quote code blocks, use the code markdown (or button)

Comment: Did you try a clean build?  If the enumeration is in one module and you use it in another module both modules will not get compiled automatically.  So clean build will force all modules to get recompiled.

Comment: Thank you jdweng, you gave  me useful hint.